# BigDecimal incompatible with ArrayList, java ClassCastException

Tags: java, arraylist, classcastexception, bigdecimal

I'm debugging some code from a different project in Eclipse, and found that even though there is no error sign (just warning),

```
try
    {   
        conn =  dss.connect();

        System.out.println("[SIGN]: Executing first step ");

        beanResultVO = executeFirstStep(usuario,conn,parametros,beanResultadoVO);

        if(beanResultVO.getResultCode() == IConstants.SWS_MSG_SUCCESSFUL){                          

            BigDecimal someCoolVar = (BigDecimal)beanResultVO.getResultObject();
            System.out.println("[SIGN]: end of the first step ");
            ((ArrayList)beanResultVO.getResultObject()).add(someCoolVar); // <--- WARNING HERE: The method add(Object) belongs to the raw type ArrayList. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized
            saveStuff(conn);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("error: "+e); // THIS SHOWS -->  java.math.BigDecimal incompatible with java.util.ArrayList
        e.printStackTrace();            
        beanResultVO.setResultCode(IConstants.SWS_MSG_ERROR);
        undoStuff(conn);
    }
```

once I execute to the line with the warning it goes directly to an exception in the try/catch block, and shows this message:

> java.math.BigDecimal incompatible with java.util.ArrayList

Here is **beanResultVO** :

```
public class BeanResultadoVO  extends BeanBase{
    private int resultCode = 0;
    private String resultMessage;
    private Object resultObject;


    public int getResultCode() {
        return resultCode;
    }
    public void setResultCode(int resultCode) {
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
    }
    public String getResultMessage() {
        return resultMessage;
    }
    public void setResultMessage(String resultMessage) {
        this.resultMessage = resultMessage;
    }
    public Object getResultObject() {
        return resultObject;
    }
    public void setResultObject(Object resultObject) {
        this.resultObject = resultObject;
    }
}
```

Now, I have tried to do

```
((ArrayList<BigDecimal>)beanResultVO.getResultObject()).add(someCoolVar);
```

getting different warning:

> Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList

But same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java all casting operations are checked. When cast cannot be done ClassCastException is thrown. In your example

```
beanResultVO.getResultObject()
```

is type of BigDecimal. BigDecimal cannot be cast to ArrayList because BigDecimal  is not a superclass of ArrayList.
If you need ArrayList you can use

```
Arrays.asList(beanResultVO.getResultObject())
```

or

```
Collections.singletonList(beanResultVO.getResultObject())
```

it returns the type you want, i.e.

```
List<BigDecimal>
```

Comment: one dummie question: why do you say its BigInteger?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that beanResultVO.getResultObject() is a BigInteger, not an ArrayList. So when you try to cast it as an ArrayList, it gives you this exception

```
((ArrayList)beanResultVO.getResultObject())
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will never run due to having

```
BigDecimal someCoolVar = (BigDecimal)beanResultVO.getResultObject();
```

just a few lines before

```
((ArrayList)beanResultVO.getResultObject()).add(someCoolVar);
```

and nothing that is changing the `resultObject` member of `beanResultVO` inbetween and `resultObject` cannot be both `ArrayList` and `BigDecimal` simultaneously.